# Tooltip on textchange of textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using Qtip2 plugin for tooltip.Tooltip plugin working fine.But i want qtip comment when someone changes quantity in textbox.

I have tried this code but it display tooltip on onfocus.

```
$("input[id$=qty]").qtip({
    content: 'click(update cart) after changing QTY',
    position: {
        corner: {
            target: 'rightMiddle',
            tooltip: 'leftMiddle'
        }
    },
    show: {
        when: {
            event: 'focus'
        }
    },
    hide: {
        when: {
            event: 'blur'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing `focus` to something else?

```
$("input[id$=qty]").qtip({
    content: 'click(update cart) after changing QTY',
    position: {
        corner: {
            target: 'rightMiddle',
            tooltip: 'leftMiddle'
        }
    },
    show: {
        when: {
            event: 'keyup' //or change, keydown,keypress, etc.
        }                  //some event that will change the value of an input
    },
    hide: {
        when: {
            event: 'blur'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi jude i have used all methods still it display first time when i just mousover or focus on textbox??

Comment: can you post this on fiddle?

Comment: I am not aware of fiddle...  this is the tetxbox i am using which i am using.   <input type="text"  id="qty" name="qtyitemnum" value="[ITEM_QUANTITY]" size="3" maxlength="5" class="txtBoxStyle" title="Click (Update Cart) after changing QTY">